# Issues web database template missing in SharePoint 2010 Final version

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have been using Sharepoint 2010 Beta for developing an Access database solution using Issues Web Database template.
After installing the final release version of Sharepoint 2010 on the production server, I have been unable to find Issues Web Database template. Has it for some reason not been included in the final version, and is there a way of including it?
What I need to do is to install the template on the server and synchronize the content with the existing solution on the developing server.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Web Database Templates are not available to create site collections.  I dont know if this can be changed.  They are available for sites and sub sites.